# Alexa Smart Home Skill disabling automatically after some when user not speak any commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa Smart Home Skill disabling automatically after some when user not speak any commands.

When User Enable Alexa Smart Home Skill It redirecting to IAM Authentication Account linking Page, then after Account linked skill working fine with user speaking commands,
But After some (around 1-2 hours )when user not speak anything , the Alexa Smart Home Skill Disabling automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems like users' refresh tokens are becoming invalid, forcing them to disable and re-enable the skill.  This usually indicates that Alexa was unable to use the provided refresh token to grab a new access/refresh token pair.

We have a general account linking debugging article with a section titled "Problem: Account linking succeeds, but after some time the customer has to link accounts again", with a few debugging steps: https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html

Comment: The off-site contact solicitation in your last paragraph is really fundamentally incompatible with the goals of this web site.